# polars apply lambda with list comprehension like pandas: Any other better way?

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, python-polars

**pandas**

```py
df['sentences'] = df['content'].str.split(pattern2)
df['normal_text'] = df['sentences'].apply(lambda x: [re.sub(pattern3, ' ', sentence) for sentence in x])
```

**polars**

```py
df = df.with_column(pl.col('content').apply(lambda x: re.split(pattern2, x)).alias('sentences'))
df = df.with_column(pl.col('sentences').apply(lambda x: [re.sub(pattern3, ' ', sentence) for sentence in x]).alias('normal_text'))
```

Amy more elegant way than this?

Comment: Can you provide an example with actual data so we can run it and see the before / after?

Comment: Ah, I found my code above for polars worked. I seemed confused by the display of the result. It looked not like list but actually it was list. So I changed my post for other question.

Answer (score 5):

The functionality is available natively in Polars via the [`.str` namespace.](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/string.html)

`.str.split()` [doesn't support regex currently](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4819)

However, similar behaviour can be achieved with [`.extract_all()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.extract_all.html) and [`.replace_all()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.replace_all.html)

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
   "content": [
      "o neHItw oHIIIIIth ree", 
      "fo urHIIfi veHIIIIs ix"
   ]
})

pattern2 = r"HI+"
pattern3 = r"\s"
replacement = ""
```

```py
df.with_columns(sentences = 
   pl.col("content")
     .str.extract_all(rf".*?({pattern2}|$)")
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ content                ┆ sentences                         │
│ ---                    ┆ ---                               │
│ str                    ┆ list[str]                         │
╞════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ o neHItw oHIIIIIth ree ┆ ["o neHI", "tw oHIIIII", "th ree… │
│ fo urHIIfi veHIIIIs ix ┆ ["fo urHII", "fi veHIIII", "s ix… │
└────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

---

The result is a column of type `list`.

We can use [`.list.eval()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.eval.html) to process each list element.

```py
(
   df.with_columns(sentences =    
      pl.col("content")
        .str.extract_all(rf".*?({pattern2}|$)")
        .list.eval(pl.element().str.replace_all(pattern2, ""))
   )
   .with_columns(normal_text = 
      pl.col("sentences").list.eval(
         pl.element().str.replace_all(pattern3, replacement)
      )
   )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┐
│ content                ┆ sentences                  ┆ normal_text             │
│ ---                    ┆ ---                        ┆ ---                     │
│ str                    ┆ list[str]                  ┆ list[str]               │
╞════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════╡
│ o neHItw oHIIIIIth ree ┆ ["o ne", "tw o", "th ree"] ┆ ["one", "two", "three"] │
│ fo urHIIfi veHIIIIs ix ┆ ["fo ur", "fi ve", "s ix"] ┆ ["four", "five", "six"] │
└────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┘
```

---

If only the `normal_text` result is needed, the steps could be combined.

```py
df.with_columns(normal_text = 
   pl.col("content").str.extract_all(rf".*?({pattern2}|$)")
     .list.eval(
        pl.element()
          .str.replace_all(pattern2, "")           
          .str.replace_all(pattern3, replacement)
     )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┐
│ content                ┆ normal_text             │
│ ---                    ┆ ---                     │
│ str                    ┆ list[str]               │
╞════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════╡
│ o neHItw oHIIIIIth ree ┆ ["one", "two", "three"] │
│ fo urHIIfi veHIIIIs ix ┆ ["four", "five", "six"] │
└────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┘
```

---

#### Performance comparison

Create larger strings for a basic comparison.

```py
N = 2000
df = pl.DataFrame({
   "content": [
      "o neHItw oHIIIIIth ree" * N, 
      "fo urHIIfi veHIIIIs ix" * N] * N
})
```

| Method | Time |
| --- | --- |
| `.str` + `.list.eval` | 8.28s |
| `.apply()` | 29.9s |

Comment: It looks complex but faster in performance than apply/lambda method?

Comment: The best way would be to measure it on your actual data - but yes - it should be faster than apply/lambda.

Comment: @dhLin I've added a performance comparison section.